# AngularFire / Firestore - Return collections and documents as a service

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-services, angular2-observables

I have several pages that reference the same node in firestore, each pulling different segments from the firestore node. For example, a summary page might pull through album title, date, genre and image, whilst another page might pull through just the title, artist and record label. A couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to turn one of the firestore queries into a service?
2. If so, does that mean the data is only read once whilst navigating across different pages (angular components) that use the same service?
3. Will the query only run again when data is modified in firestore through the observable? ("*return Observable.create(observer => {*" )

I have tried a service with the code below. However, the issue observed is that on page refresh, the data isn't present. It is however present whilst navigating through the site. I believe this is because my page is running before the observable is returned. Is there a way to wrap up the query as an observable?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
getAlbumData() {
  this.albumDoc = this.afs.doc(`albums/${this.albumId}`);
  this.album = this.albumDoc.snapshotChanges();
  this.album.subscribe((value) => {

    // The returned Data
    const data = value.payload.data();

    // Firebase Reference
    var storage = firebase.storage();

    // If album cover exists
    if (data.project_signature != undefined) {

      // Get the Image URL
      var image = data.album_cover_image;

      // Create an image reference to the storage location
      var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

      // Get the download URL and set the local variable to the result (url)
      imagePathReference.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        this.album_cover = url;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I build my observables, I try to use operators as much as I can until I get the data I want to display in my UI.

You don't want to implement too much code in the subscribe method because you break the reactive paradigm by doing so. 
Instead, extract you data in your observable and display it in your template.
Don't forget to use the async pipe in your template to display your data when it gets fetched by your application.

I would do something like this:

```
// In AlbumService
getAlbumCover(albumId: string) {
    const albumDoc = this.afs.doc(`albums/${albumId}`);
    const album_cover$ = this.albumDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      // get the album data from firestore request
      map(data => {
        return {
          id: data.payload.id,
          ...data.payload.data()
        };
      }),
      // emits data only if it contains a defined project_signature
      filter(album => album.project_signature),
      // prepare the imagePath and get the album cover from the promise
      mergeMap(album => {
        const storage = firebase.storage();
        const image = album.album_cover_image;
        const imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);
        return imagePathReference.getDownloadURL();
      })
    );
    return album_cover$;
  }
```

By doing so, when your data is updated in firestore, it will be fetched automatically by your application since you use an observable.

In your component, in the onInit() method after getting your album id from the url:
`this.album_cover$ = this.albumService.getAlbumCover(albumId);`

Finally, in my template, I would do :

`<div>{{album_cover$ | async}}</div>`

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Are there specific imports for map, filter and mergeMap? Typescript seems to throw an error with this. With the code above, can I simple import that as a service into other components and modules?

Comment: Yes, each operators need to be imported individually. For example, in your case, if you want to import map, mergeMap and filter, you will need to add that: 
`import { map, mergeMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`
And yes, you can put that into a service to access your data from any components.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I keep getting 'Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.' on 'this.album_cover = line'. To extract other data like titles, dates etc, would that be referenced in the first return just under '...data.payload.Data()'? such as 'this.albumTitle = data.albumTitle'? 

Additionally, how could this approach work for collections also?

Comment: whoops, little mistakes from my part since I called the snapshotChanges method two times in a row. The data method start with a lowercase also.
I have changed it in my answer. It should be correct now. 
All the properties of your document are returned by the data method. So, if you want to access your property 'albumTitle', you would write: `data.payload.data().albumTitle`.
For collection, it's almost the same, but it returns an array instead. Checkout this link for more details: 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges

Comment: ah fantastic. Thank you. I'll give this a go! - Also, if it's in a service, is it best to put all of the above code into the constructor? (like what's in the AngularFire docs?)

Comment: Also, what is line four referring to? (this.album_cover). Lastly, if the 'this.albumId' is referenced via the url parameters, how does the service add that to 'this.albumDoc'. If I understand it correctly, the service won't know when the album component is activated, therefore what the albumID is. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend to put this code in a service, but not in the service constructor. It must stays as a method in your service to get your data.
Currently, the album_cover is an observable in which the source is your data coming from firestore. Then, we perform transformations by adding operators to get at the end your album cover url from the promise (I will comment the code).
For your use case, in the onInit method of your component, call your service method after getting the id from your url and pass it as a parameter: 

`const albumUrl$ = this.myService.getAlbumData(albumId);`

Comment: Don't forget to return your observable when you have finished manipulating your data in your method.
In the end you get a method which takes an albumId as a parameter and return an observable which contains your album image url.

Comment: Thank you! Very kind of you to spend so much time explaining everything! Much appreciated.